# Forger Viewer setThemingColor()

Tags: autodesk-forge

The aim is to colorize selected elements.
Create service file for producing work (viewer-service.js):

```
import { Vector4 } from "three";

class ViewerService {

    /*
        Get all depended elements
    */
    getLeafNodes(model, dbIds) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree;

                dbIds = dbIds || instanceTree.getRootId();

                const dbIdArray = Array.isArray(dbIds) ? dbIds : [dbIds];
                let leafIds = [];

                const getLeafNodesRec = (id) => {
                    let childCount = 0;

                    instanceTree.enumNodeChildren(id, (childId) => {
                        getLeafNodesRec(childId);

                        ++childCount;
                    });

                    if (childCount == 0) {
                        leafIds.push(id);
                    }
                };

                for (let i = 0; i < dbIdArray.length; ++i) {
                    getLeafNodesRec(dbIdArray[i]);
                }

                return resolve(leafIds);
            } catch (ex) {
                return reject(ex);
            }
        });
    }

    /*
        Color element
    */
    add(viewer, dbids) {

        let red = new Vector4(1, 0, 0, 0.5);

        this.getLeafNodes(viewer.model, dbids)
            .then((leafNodes) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < leafNodes.length; i++) {
                    console.log(leafNodes[i]);
                    console.log(red);
                    viewer.setThemingColor(leafNodes[i], red, viewer.model, true);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => console.warn(error));
    }
}

export default new ViewerService();
```

And use this service in vue component:

```
<script>
import viewerService from "@/services/viewer-service";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      viewer: null,
      options: {
        env: "Local",
        document: this.url,
      },
      dbids: null,
    };
  },
  props: {
    url: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadViewer();
  },
  methods: {
    loadViewer() {
      let config3d = {};
      this.viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(
        this.$refs.forgeViewer,
        config3d
      );
      Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(this.options, () => {
        this.viewer.initialize();

        this.viewer.addEventListener(
          Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,
          this.onSelectionChanged
        );

        this.viewer.start(this.url, this.options);
      });
    },
    onSelectionChanged(event) {
      this.dbids = event.dbIdArray;
      console.log(this.dbids);
    },
    add() {
      viewerService.add(this.viewer, this.dbids);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

When I execute method add() it performs operations but the color of the element doesn't change.
[The console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITNvV.png) I use the latest version of Viewer. What's wrong with this code?

I also tried:

```
viewer.setThemingColor(leafNodes[i], red);
viewer.setThemingColor(leafNodes[i], red, null, true);
```

Comment: your code looks alright so can you confirm `2965` is a leaf node? can it be selected with `viewer.select(2965)`? if the issue persists can you send the offending model file (upload to an online drive of choice and drop the link) over to forge.help@autodesk.com along with the `externalId` of the problematic component so we can look into it?

Comment: Yes, ```viewer.select(2965)``` runs as expected. ```2965``` is not a leaf node, but what does it change? The method ```setThemingColor``` takes id of the root element as well as all potentical leaf elements in a cycle.

Comment: Then will it work on a leaf node? Are you on the latest 7.20? Have you tried earlier versions because we had a couple of regressions with 7.20... Either way it could as well be a model specific issue and we'd need to look at the model to be sure ...

Comment: I trired to use latest 7.20.1 and 7.1.1. It's not working neither on root, nor leaf object. I sent email with detailed description and model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. I'm using Vue.js and npm package manager for this project and sure I install the latest version of 'three.js' from package manager. But Forge Viewer requires another one, so I started using globals in project and get result.